# Ubuntu 15.10, grub freeze

Tags: grub2, 15.10

I installed linux alongside to windows 7.I made a bootable ubuntu 15.10(from official ubuntu website) on USB(program to make linux bootable downloaded from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) and when i'm choosing a system, after few seconds my PC stops and i have to reset it. If i choose quickly, everything works fine. I was looking for answers but none of does not give a clear answer. Any ideas? I'm using SSD for systems, HDD for other files.

Comment: Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn the USB instead. PDL is terrible.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby Hmm. Sure

Comment: @Fabby answered

Answer (score 2):

@Fabby suggested I put this as an answer, so here goes.

PenDriveLinux is pretty bad. A mod here is actually trying to contact Canonical and suggest an alternative be recommended on the Ubuntu website.

The alternative is called [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie). It works much better than PDL/UUI, and is able to burn any ISO, not only Linux.

Every problem people have with USB installers has been solved by using Rufus instead.